# "there's no risk in X" vs "there's no risk of X" vs "there's no risk to X"?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

I was correcting a [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/16579/revisions) on another SE site and found the following sentence, which immediately stroke me as odd:

> There's no risk to use *falda* in singular, even if there are more than one person involved.

My correction was as follows<sup>1</sup>:

> There's no risk **in using** *falda* in singular, even if there is more than one person involved.

But then I started thinking it over and wasn't so sure about my correction anymore, so I looked up several alternatives and found the following patterns:

> With Birch in command, there's **no risk of** compromise, mercy or compassion. [[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-risk)]
>
> There's **no risk of** Ebola spreading in Europe. [[The Local](http://www.thelocal.se/20141112/theres-no-risk-of-ebola-spreading-in-europe)]
>
> Australia: Heath Minister says there is “**no risk in** vaccinating children” [[Before It's News](http://beforeitsnews.com/alternative/2016/03/australia-heath-minister-says-there-is-no-risk-in-vaccinating-children-2-3327658.html)]
>
> RFU says there is **'no risk' in** giving head coach Stuart Lancaster a new six-year contract through to 2020. [[The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/rugbyunion/international/england/11134643/RFU-says-there-is-no-risk-in-giving-head-coach-Stuart-Lancaster-a-new-six-year-contract-through-to-2020.html)]
>
> For example, the French Penal Code sets out a duty to rescue where there is **no risk to** an individual, in Section 63. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omissions_in_English_criminal_law)]
>
> Europe's regulators have confirmed that there is **no risk to** consumers from BPA-based food contact materials. [[Bisphenol A](http://www.bisphenol-a-europe.org/en_GB/faqs)]

So this is what I gather:

- *No risk of X*: there's no risk X will happen
- *No risk in X*: X doesn't entail any risk
- *No risk to X*: there's no risk X will be damaged

**Am I correct? Are there any other prepositions I can use after "there's no risk", or any situations where the expressions above mean something different?**

---

<sup>1: FWIW, what the OP meant was that it is safe to use *falda* (skirt) in singular even when the speaker is talking about more than one person wearing a skirt because context generally disambiguates.</sup>

Comment: Your understanding is correct re risk {in, of, to}.   Sometimes **for** will be used instead of **to**, with the same sense.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. So I just found this: *There is **no risk to** providing a saliva sample* [[CDH Genetics](http://www.cdhgenetics.com/dhreams-study.cfm)]. Does that mean the same as *There is **no risk in** providing a saliva sample*? Is there any reason why "to" was used instead of "in"?

Comment: There's no reason to choose **to** over **in** there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your correction is justified. The examples of "risk to" have different structure and meaning from the original text.

"No risk to X" means "damage to X is unlikely". "To" is a proposition here.

But the original text is "*There's no risk to use falda" - "to" is linked with "use" (forming an infinitive), and the sentence does not refer to "damage to use falda".

Your suggested correction

> There's no risk in using falda in singular, even if there is more than one person involved.

Is definitely better than the original. Alternatively, you could change "using" to "the use of".